# tkinter - I'm trying to disable the forward / backward button but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build an image viewer that loads the images from a folder. It should have forward / backward and quit buttons. It seems to work just fine with one issue:

So I just take the image paths with this:

```
def get_files_from_folder(path, allowed_extensions):
    found_paths = []

    for (dir_path, _, file_names) in os.walk(path):
        for file_name in file_names:
            for allowed_extension in allowed_extensions:
                if file_name.lower().endswith(allowed_extension.lower()):
                    found_paths.append(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name))

                    break

    return found_paths
```

I have the tkinter UI for the image viewer:

```
class UI:
    def __init__(self, icon_path, images_folder_path):
        self.current_index = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Images')
        self.root.iconbitmap(icon_path)

        self.button_quit = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Quit', padx = 60, command = self.root.quit)
        self.button_forward = tk.Button(self.root, text = '>>', command = self.forward)
        self.button_backward = tk.Button(self.root, text = '<<', command = self.backward)

        self.button_quit.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.button_forward.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        self.button_backward.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.images_paths = get_files_from_folder(images_folder_path, ['.jpg', '.png'])
        self.tk_images = []
        print(get_files_from_folder)
        for image_path in self.images_paths:
            self.tk_images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_path)))

        self.current_image = tk.Label(image = self.tk_images[0])
        self.current_image.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 3)

        self.root.mainloop()
```

And for some reason, here when I'm using the `tk.DISABLED`, it just won't disable it

```
    def backward(self):

        if self.current_index == 0:
            self.button_backward = self.button_backward = tk.Button(self.root, text = '<<', command = self.backward, state = tk.DISABLED)

        self.current_image.grid_forget()

        self.current_index -= 1
        self.current_image = tk.Label(image = self.tk_images[self.current_index])
        self.current_image.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 3)
```

same for the forward:

```
    def forward(self):

        self.current_image.grid_forget()

        if self.current_index == len(self.tk_images)-1:
            self.button_forward = self.button_forward = tk.Button(self.root, text = '>>', command = self.forward, state = tk.DISABLED)
        else:
            self.button_forward.state = tk.ACTIVE
        self.current_index += 1
        self.current_image = tk.Label(image = self.tk_images[self.current_index])
        self.current_image.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least a couple of things wrong with your current code regarding the forward and backward `Button`s commands. As for disabling the `Button`s, that can be done by calling their `config()` method — **not** by creating a new one or assigning a new value to the existing ones `state` attribute (i.e. `self.button_forward.state = tk.ACTIVE`).

Similarly it's not a good practice to continually create new `tk.Label` widgets every time one of the buttons is pressed and the image on it changes. It's better to change the `image=` option of the existing `Label`. Doing this also often simplifies what needs to be done.

In addition your logic for clamping the `self.current_index` was flawed and would allow it to get out of range and `IndexError`s to occur. This is more complicated than I anticipated, but I think I figured out a good way to handle it, namely by putting all the logic a private method `_change_current_index()` and calling it from the forward and backward callback functions.

Lastly, user @acw1668 commented that it loading all images into memory at program start might be two slow. To avoid that, I replaced the list of all the loaded images you had (`self.tk_images`) with calls to a another new private method named `_open_image()` which caches its results by having the `functools.lru_cache` decorator applied to it. This makes the method remember what values it has already returned for a limited number of indices thereby restricting the number of them in memory at any one time.

Note I also reformatted the code to better conform to the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines to make it more readable.

```
from functools import lru_cache
import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class UI:
    IMG_CACHE_SIZE = 10

    def __init__(self, icon_path, images_folder_path):
        self.current_index = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Images')
#        self.root.iconbitmap(icon_path)

        self.button_quit = tk.Button(self.root, text='Quit', padx=60, command=self.root.quit)
        self.button_forward = tk.Button(self.root, text='>>', command=self.forward)
        self.button_backward = tk.Button(self.root, text='<<', command=self.backward)

        self.button_quit.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.button_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.button_backward.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.image_paths = get_files_from_folder(images_folder_path, ['.jpg', '.png'])
        self.current_image = tk.Label(image=self._open_image(0))
        self.current_image.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)

        self._change_current_index()  # Initializes fwd and bkd button states.
        self.root.mainloop()

    @lru_cache(maxsize=IMG_CACHE_SIZE)
    def _open_image(self, i):
        image_path = self.image_paths[i]
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_path))

    def backward(self):
        self._change_current_index(-1)

    def forward(self):
        self._change_current_index(1)

    def _change_current_index(self, delta=0):
        self.current_index += delta

        # Update state of forward and backward buttons based on new index value.
        bkd_state = (tk.DISABLED if self.current_index == 0 else tk.ACTIVE)
        self.button_backward.config(state=bkd_state)
        fwd_state = (tk.DISABLED if self.current_index == len(self.image_paths)-1 else tk.ACTIVE)
        self.button_forward.config(state=fwd_state)

        # Update image on Label.
        self.current_image.config(image=self._open_image(self.current_index))


def get_files_from_folder(path, allowed_extensions):
    found_paths = []
    for (dir_path, _, file_names) in os.walk(path):
        for file_name in file_names:
            for allowed_extension in allowed_extensions:
                if file_name.lower().endswith(allowed_extension.lower()):
                    found_paths.append(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name))
                    break
    return found_paths

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UI('.', './images_test')
```

Comment: Should it be better to update the `image` of `self.current_image` instead of recreating it inside `backward()` and `forward()` functions?

Comment: Thanks for this, however with this code now it disables the back button even when I'm on the second or third image. It stays disabled no matter what.

Comment: Zselter: It works for me. Since the state of the buttons is only changed in two places, it should be fairly easy for you to figure out what's disabling it early.

Comment: @acw1668: Yes, it's generally a good idea to update existing widgets rather than continuously create new ones. From what I understand, the discarded widgets are not reclaimed, so depending on how many of them there might be, it could be a problem.

Comment: @@acw1668: I have incorporated your suggestion into my answer. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: One more suggestion.  Loading all images into memory at program start should be avoided as it may take a long time and consume lot of memory if there are many images (especially large images) in the folder.  So better to only load the to-be displayed image whenever the `backward` or `forward` button is clicked.

Comment: Also your code has the issue @Zselter said in the comment.  `backward` button should be enabled once `forward` button is clicked and image is changed.  Same for the case when `backward` button is clicked and image is changed, `forward` button should be enabled.

Comment: A simple example: when `self.current_index` is zero and `backward` button is disabled, click `forward` button.  The `else` block in `forward()` function will be executed.  In this case, your code only enable the `forward` button, but the `backward` button should be enabled as well.

Comment: Zselter: Have you tried the latest version of my answer?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help! Everything's smooth now!